# How can I programmatically call my .net button's onclick in page load?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a onclick event that is like:

```
public void OnMyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

How can I call this from within pageload?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Event handlers are just normal methods - you can call them from anywhere within the class they're defined in - so Dan's answer is technically correct, although I feel he leaves out a bit of best-practice advice.

Instead of calling your event handler from your load event, you should move the code in your event handler into another method, and then call that method from within both your click event handler, and your page load method.

Answer (score 8):

Just call the method directly.

```
OnMyButton_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Of course, if you find yourself programmatically triggering UI events, you may want to reconsider the structure of your page.

Answer (score 4):

Refactor the code from inside the click event handler to a separate method and call the new method.

Comment: ideally the logic shoudl be in a business layer, with the web page only handeling UI.

Comment: That may be the case - although I wouldn't give such advice given the information we have. The project in question may not be complex enough to warrant a separate business layer, and adding one to such a project would be a hinderance rather than a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

```
OnMyButton_Click(this.OnMyButton, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

this function is what you need:

```
public static void DoClick(this System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn)
{
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo m = typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
        .GetMethod("OnClick", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    m.Invoke(btn, new object[] { EventArgs.Empty });
}
```